# LSTM for multivariate time-series classification with unequal timesteps

Tags: neural-networks, classification, lstm, tensorflow, keras

I am attempting to use RNN or LSTM for multivariate time-series classification of my data. A sample corresponds to an actor, a time-step corresponds to an action and a single action consists of many features. My data consists of actions occuring over a period of time, and ideally I would use my model to predict the class of the every actor based on the history of their actions. My data looks something like this:

```
Day     Actor     Action
0       A         XA1
0       A         XA2
4       B         XB1
9       A         XA3
11      B         XB2
13      C         XC1
17      A         XA4
```

And the other dimensions consists of basic features and the class such as:

```
Action     Feature1     Feature2     Feature3     Illegal?
XA1        1            0            1            0
XA2        0            1            1            0
XB1        1            1            0            0
XA3        1            1            0            1
XB2        0            0            0            0
XC1        1            1            1            0
XA4        0            1            0            0
```

The reason I am using LSTM is because the actions on their own are not enough for the classification, but the entire history of actions for each actor are needed to classify the subsequent actions. (Note above that XB1 and XA3 have the same features, but one actions is legal while the other isn't). There is a huge class imbalance in my data, so I am instead interested in classifying the actors instead of the individual actions.

Two dimensions of the tensor would look something like this:

```
A: [XA1, XA2, XA3, XA4], Class: 1
B: [XB1, XB2], Class: 0
C: [XC1], Class: 0
```

And the other dimensions consist of the action features. The label for Actor A is based on the illegal label in the original data.

Now my main two questions are:

**1)** Is it possible to produce a class for every sample (A,B,C) and use it for training/testing instead of the labels being in the time-series features?

**2)** Is it possible to proceed with LSTM given that the number of time-steps is not the same among the samples?